# i cant print out in nested loop. i tried to print the number that has only 2 factorial but it cant print out

Tags: python-3.x

i made a function to print every prime number less than number that given in the parameter. i will print the print number if the factorial of it is only 2. i made nested loop to check its factorial after the second loop over i tried to check the total of the factorial if its 2 then print it. it cant print out. why did this happen? please help me.

```
factorial = []
for nums in range(1,10):
    for num in range(1,nums+1):
        if nums % num == 0:
            factorial.append(num)
        if len(factorial) == 2:
            print(nums)
            factorial.clear()
```

Comment: thanks for your help edited my code im still a new i dont know much about it

Answer (score 0):

## This should do it btw write code with two spaces in stackoverflow //sw

```
import math

def prime_number(n):
    
    for _i in range(2,n):
        
        check_to = math.ceil(math.sqrt(_i))
        
        it = 3
        
        while True:
            
            test = _i / it
            
            if round(test) == test:
                
                prime = False
                
                break
            
            it += 2
            
            if it > check_to:
                
                prime = True
                
                break
            
        if prime:
            
            print(_i)


prime_number(10)
```